# Delphi 7 / IBQuery under Win 7 x64 works only after a second click

Tags: delphi, interbase

I have a problem with some Ibquery's on some machines with Win7 x64. The problem is that the query doesn't work the first time, I hit the button and the query is empty, I hit(not double click) it again and it works how it should. I can't find the problem, does anyone have ideas or had same problems?

Comment: please post your query and/or code

Comment: What button? Queries don't have buttons. Your question doesn't make any sense. Please edit it and try to add some details, and while you are please remember that we have no information other than what you tell us in your question. We can't see your code, your application, your monitor, or read your mind from here. You need to provide the details so we can understand what your problem is if you expect us to help you solve it. :)

Answer (score 0):

While some further details will be helpful, and probably required to provide an accurate answer, the sense I get out of your question is this: You are talking about an Interbase Express component, IBQuery, and I will assume your button is the form button as neither an IBQuery nor a Query have buttons, as noted.

When you select the form button, what does happen - if anything? Are you certain that just the IBQuery component is not working, or could it be that the form is not doing anything - maybe not receiving the first button click at all. I have one new mini notebook with Win7 Home Premium, 32 bit, that is behaving that way on all kinds of things. Have you tried other things on the problem machines?